# How to make a dynamic source for .getRange() in Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dynamic, range

**Original Question:**
I have multiple tabs in a Google Spreadsheet that represent different data sources. Currently, I have a variable (*var = quote1location*) that is equal to the sheet name that I would like to get my data from based on other logic.

Pretend that *quote1location* can equal 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2', or 'Sheet3' depending on the logic but for this case, it equals 'Sheet1'.

***var totalpeople = quote1location.getRange('A1').getValue();***

In the function above, Apps Script will return an error saying 'quote1location.getRange is not a function' because Apps Script is not substituting the value of the variable that I have designated ('Sheet1') but is using the variable name ('quote1location' instead. I would like Apps Script to process this as 'Sheet1.getRange('A1').getValue()'.

Your help would be appreciated

**Answer:**
Thank you all for your responses. What I was trying to do is use a string in the 'getRange()' function. Pretend I had two Google Sheets named 'Sheet1' and 'Sheet2' and I had a variable that helped me determine what sheet to grab as my data reference. I was trying to set a variable as either (*var source = 1*) or (*var source = 2*) so that I could then use this variable in my getRange() function like this: *('Sheet' + source).getRange('A1').getValue();*

What I was trying to do here is if *var source = 1*, then I would get my data from 'Sheet1'. If the *var source = 2*, then I would get my data from 'Sheet2'.

The issue (as mentioned by those who responded) is that I was trying to use .getRange() on a string, not an object like a specific spreadsheet. Instead of using *var source = 2* or *var source = 1* I should be using

```
ss = SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

if(somevariable = somecondition){
var source = ss.getSheetbyName('Sheet1')
}

if(someothervariable = someothercondition){
var source = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2')
}
```

Now when I use getRange()' on  '*source*', it will be calling the sheet that I have designated rather than trying to retrieve a range from a string which will not work.

Thank you very much to all who provided feedback.

Comment: I would probably just use a validation column to selection which data source sheet I want but you haven't provided any information as to what you quote sheet looks like

Comment: You need to the learn **Javascript types**. Specifically, the difference between string type and a object type.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking to do:

```
const quote1Location = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                     .getSheetByName(`Sheet1`)

const totalPeople = quote1Location.getRange(`A1`).getValue()
```

Alternatively:

```
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const quote1Location = `Sheet1`

const totalPeople = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(quote1Location)
                               .getRange(`A1`)
                               .getValue()
```

Whether these are the exact syntax you're hoping to use or not, I hope this helps you better understand how to accomplish accessing a Sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, you are defining the sheet name in both of these examples. I need to use a variable to determine which sheet I am calling ; 

var quote1location = 'Sheet1' ; 
var totalpeople = quote1location.getRange('A1').getValue() will fail because Apps Script cannot capture 'Sheet1' from the variable

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I'm showing you. Please look at how to get a Sheet by name and set it to a variable: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename

Comment: @DavidSteele Please explain how plan to calculate your quotes and what your quote form might look like.  At this point we have no idea what your plans are.